# XRDP on Ubuntu 16.04 Sessions

Tags: 16.04, xrdp

We are using XRDP on Ubuntu 16.04. We have it set now where after a user disconnects, they are re-connected to their old session.

However, if a new person connects (same credentials, just a different IP address), they get a new session.

How can we force everyone to use one session?

Answer (score 0):

By replacing the default VNC Server with the X11VNC component, you should be able to reconnect to your existing remote session.  You will be able to disconnect from your session and reconnect and find the same desktop session as before.  If you were working on a spreadsheet, you will be able to resume your work on it.  Cool, isn’t it

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf libtool libpam0g-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback 
echo  ”gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback” > ~/.xsession
sudo apt-get install x11vnc
```

Update the /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini:

```
sudo nano /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

Create a new section :

```
[xrdp8]
name=Reconnect
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5910
```

**You should check these reference :**

Reference 1 : [How to reconnect to the existing session while using the xrdp package from Ubuntu Repository](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4471)

Reference 2 : [How to reconnect to the “same” remote session](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4168)

Comment: I am getting this error: 
`E: Package 'gnome-session-fallback' has no installation candidate`

Also, when I try to connect through RDP it says connection refused.